# Windows Ribbon Framework: Multi-level gallery implementation

Tags: c++, winapi, ribbon, ribbon-control, windows-ribbon-framework

Is it possible to implement a multi-level dynamic gallery (such as below)?  I don't see a way to specify attributes for 2nd level gallery controls e.g. HasLargeItems/Type values at run-time.

Thanks in advance;

[image]